# (How) can i access relative position of qml element to main window

Tags: qml

I have a qml element and want to show a (own) tooltip element as a new window right above this element. for this i need the absolute screen position to place the new window (AFAIK).

i got as far that the regular approach is to use "mapToItem" to get the relative position, but i cannot get to the "main window" - because the element in question is located within a "Loader" (which in this case is again located in another Loader).

So my question is: Is it possible to access the mainWindow from inside the dynamically loaded component, or is there maybe another easier way to anchor a new (tooltip) window right above an element ?

**EDIT**

mapToGlobal would probably work too, but i have to use qt 5.6.
i finally got it to work by setting the main window as a context property in c++:

this->qmlEngine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("mainWindow", this->root);

and in qml i can then access the main window position (on screen) and add the relative position the item has to the shown window like that:

```
tooltipWindow.setX(mainWindow.x +item1.mapToItem(item2,0,0).x )
```

Comment: Do you have some code to play with? I think the main problem is, that `Window` does not inherit from `Item` so there should be no `mapToItem` or `mapFromItem`-Method available.

Comment: Do you really intend to use a new `Window` for this tooltip, or rather a new `Item` within a common `Window`?

Comment: And do you intend to have it as a child of the *mainWindow* or as a sibling?

Comment: According to the documentation, if you pass "null" as the item to `mapToItem` then the coordinates get mapped to the "view", in your case that should be the window.

Comment: You can use Item::mapToGlobal() introduced in Qt 5.7 / QtQuick 2.7: http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToGlobal-method

Answer (score 0):

The `Window` item has `contentItem` especially for that

> [read-only] contentItem : Item
>
> The invisible root item of the scene.

So you can refer to `Window.contentItem` as if it was `Window`:

```js
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 300

    Component {
        id: testElement
        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "orange"
            border { width: 1; color: "#999" }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onEntered: tooltip.show(true);
                onExited: tooltip.show(false);
                onPositionChanged: tooltip.setPosition(mapToItem(mainWindow.contentItem,mouse.x, mouse.y));
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        x: 40
        y: 50
        Item {
            x: 80
            y: 60
            Loader {
                sourceComponent: testElement
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: tooltip
        visible: false
        width: 100
        height: 20
        color: "lightgreen"
        border { width: 1; color: "#999" }
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "I'm here"
        }
        function show(isShow) {
            tooltip.visible = isShow;
        }
        function setPosition(point) {
            tooltip.x = point.x - tooltip.width / 2;
            tooltip.y = point.y - tooltip.height;
        }
    }
}
```

As for me I would reparent tooltip Item to hovered item itself at `MouseArea.onEntered` and so you can avoid position recalculation etc.:

```js
onEntered: tooltip.show(true, rect);
onExited: tooltip.show(false);
onPositionChanged: tooltip.setPosition(mouse.x, mouse.y);
```

...

```js
function show(isShow, obj) {
    obj = (typeof obj !== 'undefined' ? obj : null);
    if(obj !== null) {
        tooltip.parent = obj;
    }
    tooltip.visible = isShow;
}

function setPosition(x, y) {
    tooltip.x = x - tooltip.width / 2;
    tooltip.y = y - tooltip.height;
}
```